# Processing on iOS with Intel's Multi-OS Engine

Tags: java, ios, processing

I was looking for a way to develop iOS apps with Java. Especially Java because I want to be able to use Processing as a Java library.
First I found RoboVM. Just to find out Microsoft did shut it down after they bought Xamarin.
Then I found Intel's Multi-OS Engine, which is a technical preview right now. It looks like you can develop an Android app just like you used to do with Java and Android Studio. Then you rewrite the UI (and probably some iOS specific API calls) and build it for iOS. Either on a Mac with Xcode or in Intel's build cloud (which seems to be free).

Using Processing in Android apps is not a new thing (even if it would be new to me). But it looks like with iOS apps it's different.
Since you have to rewrite the UI for iOS, I not sure if it's still possible to use Processing the same way.

If that's not possible I wonder if it would possible/a good idea to call loadPixels() at the end of the draw function, then read all the pixel values and write them to an iOS UI element.
Would it use up to much CPU power to do that every single frame or could this be a solution if there's no other way?

Of couse that would only give me UI output for processing. Somehow I still have to get touch events into processing if I want to handle those events there.
In jQuery I can not only register a callback for an event with `$("#myButton").click(myFunction);` but also simulate an event with `$("#myButton").click();`. When you call the click function without any arguments the event is triggered on that DOM element instead of registering a callback for that DOM element and that event.
Is there a way in Processing to do something like that?
If so, I could get touch events from Multi-OS Engine an then pass them to Processing.

Answer (score 0):

You can think of Processing as actually being two things: it's a library, and it's a set of tools that handle exporting for you.

If you're using the Processing editor, then you're using the tools that handle exporting for you. You can deploy as a Java application, or as an Android app, or even as JavaScript through Processing.js. These tools take your Processing code and then converts it into the format needed to deploy your code.

However, you can also use Processing as a Java library, just like you would any other Java library. You do this by simply adding Processing's jars to your classpath, and then you can call Processing functions exactly like you can call any other library. If you do this, then you're in charge of writing your code and then deploying it. But it's certainly possible to use Processing as a Java library to draw to an image, and then draw that image to a native component.

Where it gets tricky is that you can't just write Java for iOS, so you can't just write code that uses Processing as a Java library. That's what RoboVM helped with. You might want to check out one of the alternatives mentioned in [RoboVM's closing announcement](https://robovm.com/robovm-winding-down/):

> Depending on where you are in the development of your apps, there are several options available to move forward, including tools that will help you port to Xamarin, and alternative Java SDKs which target iOS. In particular, libGDX has just announced their support for Intel’s Multi-OS Engine, which means there is an alternative for the majority of RoboVM’s active developers.

Another option you might consider is using Processing.js or p5.js to deploy as html and JavaScript. Then you could just visit your webpage on your phone's browser.

Comment: >"However, you can also use Processing as a Java library"
That's exactly what I'm doing.

>"Where it gets tricky is that you can't just write Java for iOS"
In the past? Yes. But today? I thought that's what Multi-OS Engine is for. I thought Multi-OS Engine could be a good RoboVM replacement.
Or am I misunderstanding what Multi-OS Engine is doing? I expected Intel ported the JVM to iOS.

I also thought about using Processing.js. But I think the performance wouldn't be very good. I already tryed Processing.js in a desktop browser and the performance was really bad.

Comment: @JuSchu Okay, so it sounds like you've got some options to try. What exactly is your question now?